Median of Mixed Random Variable
I have the following CDF
$$
F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
1 - p e^{-x} & x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
I found $\mathcal{X} = \{ 0\} \hspace{0.1cm} \cup (0,\infty)$ with $P(X = 0) = 1-p$ and $f_X(x) = pe^{-x}$. How i can find the median of $X$? I plan to get into cases for values ​​of $p$. If $p<0.5$ then we must find $m$ such that $1-p + \int_{0}^{m} p e^{-x} dx = 0.5$. If $p = 0.5$ then $p = 0.5$ is median. If $p > 0.5$ is where I have problems, in this case would it not exist? I appreciate any help or suggestion.

The definition of the median $m$ is the smallest number such that $F_X(m) \ge \dfrac{1}{2}$.
From the definition, we have
$$
    F_X(m) \ge \dfrac{1}{2} \Longleftrightarrow \begin{cases} 1 - pe^{-m} \ge \dfrac{1}{2} \\ m \ge 0 \end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow \begin{cases} e^{-m} \le \dfrac{1}{2p} \\ m \ge 0 \end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow m \ge \max\{\ln(2p), 0\}
$$
Thus, the median of this distribution is
$$
    m = \max\{\ln(2p), 0\} = \begin{cases} \ln(2p), \text{ if } 1/2 \le p \le 1 \\ 0, \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}
$$
